# How to use AskPattern.ask in Akka Typed? (Java/Kotlin)

Tags: java, kotlin, akka, actor, akka-typed

I'm having a bit of trouble using the Ask Pattern in Akka Typed. I'm trying to send a message from outside an actor, and attempted to follow [this example](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#request-response-with-ask-from-outside-an-actor). However, I think that my setup is a bit different from the example:

```
object SimulatorManager {

    fun create(): Behavior<SimulatorManagerMessage> {
        val state = ... // initialize state
        return waitingToStartSimulation(state)
    }

    private fun waitingToStartSimulation(state: SimulatorManagerState): Behavior<SimulatorManagerMessage> {
        return Behaviors.receive { context, message ->
            when (message) {
                is StartSimulation -> {
                    // start simulation and update state
                    waitingToStartSimulation(state)
                }
                else -> Behaviors.same()
            }
        }
    }
}

sealed class SimulatorManagerMessage

data class StartSimulation(
    val consumer: ConsumerCredentials,
    val storeId: Long,
    val itemId: Long,
    val simTimeIncrement: Double,
    val realTimeIncrement: Double,
) : SimulatorManagerMessage()
```

I'm trying to send a `StartSimulation` message to `SimulatorManager` from outside of the Actor System. However, I'm getting stuck on what to input for the `replyTo` function parameter.

```
class SimulatorController(
    val systemRef: ActorSystem<SimulatorManagerMessage>,
    private val simManagerRef: ActorRef<SimulatorManagerMessage>
) {

    fun startSimulation(request: StartSimulationRequest) {
        val msg = request.toMessage()
        val result = AskPattern.ask<SimulatorManagerMessage, SimulatorController>(
            simManagerRef,
            { replyTo ->  },        // what should go here? 
            Duration.ofSeconds(15),
            systemRef.scheduler()
        )
    }
}
```

It says that the type of the parameter should be `Function<ActorRef<SimulatorController!>!, SimulatorManagerMessage!>!`, but I don't know how to go about creating a function like this. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Is `StartSimulation` the only class extending `SimulatorManagerMessage`?

Comment: There is also `SimulationEnded`, and a case `is SimulationEnded` in `waitingToStartSimulation` to handle this message -- removed for brevity though!

Comment: I ask because, if there's not an `ActorRef<SimulatorController>` field in `SimulatorManagerMessage`, you're going to need to tweak the protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replyTo ->`  function constructs the message to send and injects a reference to  the actor which will receive the message in reply.

This is because, in order to be asynchronous, what the ask pattern effectively does is:

- send a message to some actor (call it "A")
- spawn an actor (actor "B") for the sole purpose of receiving the reply and completing a future with that reply (or failing that future if the timeout is reached; actor "B" will stop itself as soon as it receives a message or time out)

In classic (untyped) Akka, the message would be constructed the recipient can determine the `sender` of every message, so the ask pattern is pretty simple (though, when sending an ask from an actor, you have to be careful with the resulting future: basically the only safe thing you can do is adapt the message and pipe it to your mailbox).

In Akka Typed, because the `ActorRef` now governs which messages can be sent, `sender` isn't available.  So now you have to explicitly model the type of the expected reply in the messages making up the protocol.

This is where I confess that this is the first Kotlin I've written, but you might have something like:

```
sealed class GradebookCommand

data class GetGradeFor(val student: String, val replyTo: ActorRef<GradeForStudent>): GradebookCommand()

data class GradeForStudent(val student: String, val score: Int, val outOf: Int)

sealed class GradebookRouterCommand

data class GetGradebookActorFor(val classId: String, val replyTo: ActorRef<GradebookIs>): GradebookRouterCommand()

data class GradebookIs(val classId: String, val gradebookActor: ActorRef<GradebookCommand>)
```

So assuming that `gradebookRouter` is an `ActorRef<GradebookRouterCommand>`, you'd ask with

```
val classId: String = "asdf"
val gradebookFuture: CompletionStage<GradebookIs> =
  AskPattern.ask<GradebookRouterCommand, GradebookIs>(
    gradebookRouter,
    { replyTo -> GetGradebookActorFor(classId, replyTo) },
    Duration.ofSeconds(15),
    systemRef.scheduler
  )
```

`gradebookFuture` will eventually be completed with the `GradebookIs` message that `gradebookRouter` caused to be sent in reply (I use that wording because, one of the benefits of being explicit about `replyTo` is that it facilitates delegating the work to another actor: you can do that in Akka Classic also, but there's some subtlety around preserving the sender which is easy to mess up).

```
// This is perhaps where my Kotlin/Java futures code goes off the rails
val student: String = "Parry Hotter"
val gradeFuture: CompletionStage<GradeForStudent> =
  gradebookFuture.thenComposeAsync({ gradebook ->
    AskPattern.ask<GradebookCommand, GradeForStudent>(
      gradebook,
      { replyTo -> GetGradeFor(student, replyTo) },
      Duration.ofSeconds(15),
      systemRef.scheduler
    )})
```

Disclaimer: the subtleties of Java/Kotlin's type system relative to Scala's (e.g around covariance/contravariance) may make that code not work, but I hope that it makes things reasonably clear.

TL;DR: make sure to have fields in your messages that serve as Reply-To addresses.  They don't have to be named `replyTo`, though that's definitely emerged as a convention.